# How to continue execution of a script after using 'script' command

Tags: linux, bash

so I am writing a bash script to create some VMs and I need to log my command line's output so at a certain point I am trying to use `script` command, but it cuts my script off until i exit the command, 
is there a way to continue execution of my script and log my command line?

The script looks like:

```
script screen.log
for i in 1 2 3
do
onetemplate instantiate "mano"  --user $CUSER --endpoint $CENDPOINT
done
exit
```

and i need to cut it at exit.

Answer (score 1):

Just `script` starts a new shell. To have `script` run a command use `script -c` *command*. This is all documented in the [manual page](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/bsdutils/script.1.en.html).

You may want to try:

```
export CUSER=...
export CENDPOINT=...
script screen.log <<\EOF
for i in 1 2 3
do
  onetemplate instantiate "mano"  --user $CUSER --endpoint $CENDPOINT
done
EOF
```

(The `export` is required to make the variables `CUSER` and `CENDPOINT` available in the shell run by `script`.)

Comment: This does not seem to work, it logs a part of my script and pretty much crashes next.

Comment: @Laris: More specifically? What doesn't work? It should execute `onetemplate instantiate "mano"  --user $CUSER --endpoint $CENDPOINT` three times and log the results in `screen.log`. By the way, what's wrong with `onetemplate instantiate ... >> screen.log`? I'm curious why you chose `script` as your logging method.

Comment: I tried to use the command > file method, but if i do the command does not work at all, I think it is just a problem with one-tools, but this is the output your part of a script returns https://prnt.sc/hoi2l2 even if I type my password in, it does not do anything further,

Answer (score 0):

> What if I used the -c option, how would i do it, because if i use it like
>
> ```
> script -c onetemplate instantiate "mano" --user xxxxxx --endpoint xxxxxx
> ```
>
> it says that --user is unrecognized option

You'd have to quote the entire command, e. g.

```
script -c "onetemplate instantiate mano --user xxxxxx --endpoint xxxxxx"
```